# Efficiency: HashMap check containsKey() vs always put()

Tags: java, hashmap

If I have a HashMap and I want to insert key value pairs with a lot of duplicates, is it better to do: 
`if (!map.containsKey(key)) map.put(key, value);` or simply do `map.put(key,value);` regardless of if the key/value pair already exists?

Comment: This is not about efficiency : it's about what you want ? Keep only the first and never overwrite OR overwrite each time you find the key again OR compute something between existing value and new one

Comment: @azro the key/value pairs are duplicates as in existing value and new value for a particular key is always the same, I am just not sure if the `put` method is heavy enough to make checking for existing key worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the dupes, just do `map.put(key, value);`. That way, you don't do an extra O(1) lookup (which includes hashing the `key` and then checking if it exists).

In the worst case, this can save you about `n-1` extra lookups for the case where the exact same `(key, value)` pair is inserted repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly the answer is it makes no real difference. First get the code correct. The profile it (which you don't seem to have done or you'd know for this case). Don't go around randomly optimising/obfuscating stuff because it seemed like a good idea.

Typically the biggest performance hit will be in loading and compiling the code. Therefore, the shortest, simplest code is probably already optimal.

Comment: I agree that it probably won't make any difference, especially with my small dataset. I am just trying to learn the most efficient way of putting a dataset into a map. Profiling it and finding out the result on my own is a great learning experience but its more reinventing the wheel if the study is done before hand? I guess I am just mainly interested to see if put() is light enough to offset the extra lookup in containsKey().

Answer (score 3):

You should use the method `putIfAbsent`. if you are concerned about overwriting the value. This method is available Java 8 onwards.

It has the same time complexity as `put`.

If you are okay with overwriting with the latest value, just go for `put`.

Answer (score 1):

`Map::put` overwrites entries with the same key, so it would be more efficient to `.put` without checking if the map already contains the key.

Answer (score 1):

Both `put` and `contain` have the same asymptotic runtime so using both will at max be an 2x increase, which is constant. So your asymptotic runtime will not change. But since `put` will just override any existing value (and even return the old value, and `null` if it is new), it is this 2x factor faster.

Answer (score 1):

I am in similar situation, decided to code up a quick little test to definitively decide:

```
private static void TestMapAccess(int loops) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapA = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapB = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapC = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        mapA.put(i, 1);
        mapB.put(i, 1);
        mapC.put(i, 1);
    }
    
    System.out.println("=====" + loops + "=====");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("run: containsKey()");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    
    for (int i=0; i<loops; i++) {
        int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10050);
        if (!mapA.containsKey(rand)) {
            mapA.put(rand, 1);
        }
    }
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("estimatedTime: " + estimatedTime / 1_000_000_000.);
    
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("run: just put it");
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    
    for (int i=0; i<loops; i++) {
        int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10050);
        mapB.put(rand, 1);
    }
    estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("estimatedTime: " + estimatedTime / 1_000_000_000.);
    
    
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("run: put if absent");
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    
    for (int i=0; i<loops; i++) {
        int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10050);
        mapC.putIfAbsent(rand, 1);
    }
    estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("estimatedTime: " + estimatedTime / 1_000_000_000.);
}
```

Output for running at various loops parameter values:

```
=====100000=====
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: containsKey()
estimatedTime: 0.019388125
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: just put it
estimatedTime: 0.011162
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: put if absent
estimatedTime: 0.012437
=====1000000=====
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: containsKey()
estimatedTime: 0.03442175
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: just put it
estimatedTime: 0.030184333
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: put if absent
estimatedTime: 0.01281975
=====100000000=====
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: containsKey()
estimatedTime: 1.734175125
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: just put it
estimatedTime: 0.855194542
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: put if absent
estimatedTime: 0.798932875
=====2000000000=====
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: containsKey()
estimatedTime: 14.871508583
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: just put it
estimatedTime: 17.005798667
-----------------------------------------------------------
run: put if absent
estimatedTime: 15.617718958
```

I ran this multiple times with only slight variations in results. actually, most of the time, when loops is only 100000, containsKey is the slowest by a factor of 2 or more. As you increase loops by several magnitudes, it slowly evens out and even becomes more efficient. Originally I was testing only the first 2 cases, not put if absent, and my guess was it was due to java garbage collection. From what I could find online, when you put() overwrite an existing value it drops it and the garbage collector needs to clean it up, which seems to negate any efficiency from not doing a containsKey check

What's interesting is that with putIfAbsent, we see a mix between containsKey and put. I suppose at the end of the day, its only a matter of seconds between the 3 cases at the highest loops value, but it is consistently this way.